# Poetry install ChefBuildError

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

Poetry install fails with ChefBuildError: Backend operation failed: HookMissing('build_editable')

My poetry version is `1.4.2`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

I believe this is caused by a change to how the `build-backend` is defined in the `pyproject.toml` between `poetry ^1.3` and `poetry ^1.4`. Assuming you have `poetry ^1.4` installed you have two options:

1. In your `pyproject.toml` change `build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"` to `build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"`
2. If, like me you have other code the assumes `poetry ^1.3` then simply downgrade you poetry version `poetry self update 1.3.2`

---

If you go with option 2 you may get a bunch of `RuntimeError hash for xxx` errors. If that's the case you will also need to `rm -r ~/.cache/pypoetry/artifacts` and `rm -r ~/.cache/pypoetry/cache`.

Answer (score 1):

Does your project name differ from your src directory?

e.g. project name is `py-project` and src dir is `scripts`, then
try adding
`packages = [{include = "scripts"}]`
to your `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "py-project"
...
packages = [{include = "scripts"}]
```

Comment: Yes, my project did differ from the src directory, but I was using the `packages = [{include = "custom_name"}]` field in the `pyproject.toml`. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Very well explained. Worked for me, thanks.